# Python: Create pandas dataframe from multiple csv.gz extracting von CSVs only specified column(s)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Several posts explain how to loop through a folder, or to extract all (or:specific) files from a given zip, or to create a pandas data frame from several CSVs in a file. Alas I am lacking experience to combine all these code snippets into something that works - Can someone help me, please?

What I currently have:

```
import gzip
import csv
import json
import pandas as pd

path =r'C:\\Users\\folder_with_zipped_files' 
File_List= glob.glob(path + "/*.csv.gz")
frame = pd.DataFrame()
list_ = []
for file_ in File_List:
    df = pd.read_csv(File_List, compression='gzip', header=0,sep=',',  error_bad_lines=False)
    collectfiles.append(df)
allfiles = pd.concat(collectfiles)
```

This throws the Error:

```
ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'list'>
```

Thanks a million for any advice and help -it's much appreciated!

Comment: You're passing the list not the filepaths in your list, you want `df = pd.read_csv(file_,....`

Comment: @user2006697, I am linking to a duplicate which has precisely the same method you are attempting. Note that your `collectfiles` doesn't seem to be defined anywhere.